# extracting JSON value and using it

Tags: python, json, python-requests, request

I am sending simple request and I am getting JSON response:

```
{'status': 'success', 'orders': [{'id': '1666543', 'link': 'asd.com', 'quantity': '111'}]}
```

My code for response:

```
response = requests.get(url, params=params)
response.json()
wynik = response.json()
print(response.json())
with open('data.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(response.text, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

It saves to data.json but in one line.

What I need is, to use the 'link' value in my selenium script.
So the whole concept is to have it 100% automated.
I am sending a request, I am getting the response and I am using this response value of 'link' in another script.

I have no idea how to extract the link value.

I will be grateful for help.

Answer (score 1):

If the data you're getting is the one you shared at the beginning of your question, then to extract the link :

```
link = wynik['orders'][0]['link']
```

This will work assuming you have one object in the orders array (it's an array, I hope you noticed that), if you have multiple objects and therefore want to extract multiple links, then you need a loop and that will be a different question that requires a different answer. If it's the case let me know.

Comment: Thanks for reply. So now, it works like this: response = requests.get(url, params=params)
response.json()
wynik = response.json()
print(response.json())
link = wynik['orders'][0]['link']

And it throws an error: link = wynik['orders'][0]['link']
KeyError: 'orders'

Comment: Please do a res = response.content, print that and post it here in the comment